# I have a company MacBook Pro and I no longer can see my username on the login screen

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, password, login-screen

I have a MacBook Pro given to me by my IT department. The macbook has 2 accounts:

- Local Administrator
- My Account

Today, when I turned on the Macbook, my account didn't appear in list of accounts to sign into. The only account on the MacBook is the Local Administrator, and I don't have its password.

Is this a bug, or have I done something wrong? I don't remember deleting anything or even remotely playing with anything that could do this.

I am using OS X El Capitan 10.11  with a 2015 MacBook Pro.

Comment: Since this is a managed system, owned by the company you work for, you should contact the IT department.

Comment: Does "Other" appear?

Comment: @Peanut No. only 'local adminstrator'

Comment: What appears when you click Local Administrator?

Comment: just a textField to enter the password for it.

Comment: What happens if you type your password?

Comment: :) Obviously, it does't go through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed! Had to go IT department.

The IT Department didn't enable/setup Filevault properly. They just had to login with their credentials and set it